# How to solve this system differential equations to determine the local flow of a smooth vector field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to calculate the local flow of the following smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $X:\mathbb{R}^2\to T\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by $X=(x^2-x^1)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}-(x^1+x^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$.

To do this, I have to resolve the following sistem of differential equations:

\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\theta^p(t)^1=\theta^p(t)^2-\theta^p(t)^1 \\
\frac{d}{dt}\theta^p(t)^2=-(\theta^p(t)^1+\theta^p(t)^2)\\
\theta^p(0)=p 
\end{cases}

for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$. (Where $\theta^p(t)^i $ is the $i$-component function of $\theta^p(t)$ )

I know the solution should be $\theta^p(t)=(p^1e^{-t}\cos t+p^2e^{-t}\sin t,-p^1e^{-t}\sin t+p^2e^{-t}\cos t)$ defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any hint/ suggestion/ strategy/ observation on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Your system can be written as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot{\theta_p^1}\\\dot{\theta_p^2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1& 1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\theta_p^1\\\theta_p^2\end{pmatrix},$$
which is a first order linear equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and notice that one has:
$$\exp\left(t\begin{pmatrix}-1& 1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}\cos(t)&e^{-t}\sin(t)\\-e^{-t}\sin(t)&e^{-t}\cos(t)\end{pmatrix},$$
whence the result.

*Remark.* I must explain how I compute this matrix exponential, I diagonalize it over $\mathbb{C}$, finding its eigenvalues are $(-1-i)t$ and $(-1+i)t$ and the change of basis matrix is given by $\begin{pmatrix}i&-i\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

*Reminder.* Let $A$ be a square matrix, then one has:
$$\dot{x}=Ax\iff\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{tA}x=0\iff x=x(0)e^{-tA},$$
the point being that the derivative of $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ is $t\mapsto Ae^{tA}$ and that $e^{-tA}e^{tA}=I$.

Comment: Thank-you very much! I don't know the theory behind your answer, and [Here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) it ist not mentioned the case in which the eigenvalues are complex. Can you also provide me a reference for the theory behind your answer?

Comment: I have added a little addendum on the resolution of a linear system of differential equations of order $1$. Regarding the complex eigenvalues case, there is no more to it than the real eigenvalues case, the point is that $\exp(PAP^{-1})=P\exp(A)P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The method in C. Falcon's solution applies in a much broader setting (all systems of linear, constant-coefficient, homogeneous o.d.e.s of $n$ functions in $n$ variables). But if you don't have the machinery at hand, here's a naive method:

**Hint** Differentiating, say, the first equation in the system gives
$$\ddot\theta{}^1 = -\dot\theta{}^1 + \dot\theta{}^2 = -(-\theta{}^1 + \theta^2) - (\theta^1 + \theta^2) = -2\theta^2 = -2 (\dot\theta{}^1 + \theta^1) ,$$
and rearranging gives the o.d.e.
$$\boxed{\ddot\theta{}^1 + 2 \dot\theta{}^1 + 2 \theta^1 = 0}$$
in $\theta^1$ alone. (For legibility we've denoted $\theta^i := \theta^p(t)^i$.) NB this is a second-order equation, so to find a unique solution, we need two conditions, say, on $\theta^1(0)$ and $\dot\theta{}^1(0)$---can you find these?